# Laravel Query retrieves only one pair of values using relationship 'Join' between two tables

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

Im trying to query products table that displays the following schema in database  ->

Table 1 -> products:

Table:

[image]

With a relationship with table products_details in model product.php ->

```
public function productdetails()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\ProductDetails', 'productId', 'id');
    }
```

Table 2 -> products_details table displays many value pair (name / value ) for each product:

Table:

[image]

With a relationship with table products in model productdetails.php ->

```
public function product()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Models\Product', 'productSku', 'productId');
}
```

Using Tinker to query model I run:

> App\Models\Product::join('products_details', 'products.productSku',
>   '=', 'products_details.productId')->take(1)->get();

gives result:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#1787
     all: [
       App\Models\Product {#1779
         id: 1,
         productName: "Samsung - Galaxy Core Prime 4G",
         productSku: "3953367",
         more info...
         created_at: "2017-04-08 18:28:46",
         updated_at: "2017-04-08 18:28:46",
         deleted_at: null,
         productId: 3953367,
         name: "Operating System",
         value: "Android 4.4 KitKat",
       },
     ],
   }
```

My question is, how can I query results in order to receive all name/value associated to productId, taking into consideration right now I only receive the first pair of values contained at product_details table, but not all the name/values associated with that productId.

```
     productId: 3953367,
     name: "Operating System",
     value: "Android 4.4 KitKat",
```

thank you!

------------------------------- UPDATE----------------------------------

I made a mistake and in comments they address a solution. The correct query must be:

```
 App\Models\Product::where('productSku', '=', SkuNumber)
                   ->join('products_details', 'products.productSku', '=', 'products_details.productId')
                   ->get()
```

Comment: If you add a `where` clause to the `productId` and remove the `get(1)`?

Comment: Try to remove the `->take(1)` in your tinker query ;)

Comment: @Adrenaxus you were right!. thank you so much.

Comment: Glad I could help. Credits also to @ka_lin who came up with the same solution a few seconds before me ;)

Comment: @ka_lin thank you for your answer, was correct!

Answer (score 0):

Solution:
I made a mistake and in comments @Adrenaxus and @ka_lin addressed a solution. The correct query must be:

```
App\Models\Product::where('productSku', '=', SkuNumber)
                   ->join('products_details', 'products.productSku', '=', 'products_details.productId')
                   ->get()
```